# How to list the given data in ascending order. The columns "Account name " and " Account status"

Tags: python, django, sorting

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQWsh.png)

views.py

```py
def listEngagements(request):

    active=Engagement.objects.filter(status="Active")

    completed=Engagement.objects.filter(status="Completed")

    datas_list=active|completed

    query = request.GET.get('q')

    if query:

        datas_list = Engagement.objects.filter(engagementName__contains=query)

    paginator = Paginator(datas_list, 20) # 6 datas per page

    page = request.GET.get('page',1)

    try:

        datas = paginator.page(page)

    except PageNotAnInteger:

        datas = paginator.page(1)

    except EmptyPage:

        datas = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    return render(request,'engagement.html',{'datas':datas,'username':username})
```

models

```py
class Engagement(models.Model):
    engagementName = models.CharField(default=" ",max_length=100,null=True,blank=True)
    engagementValue=models.IntegerField(default=0)
    email = models.EmailField(null=True,blank=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=50,null=True)
 
    class Meta:
        ordering =['engagementName']
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.engagementName)
```

html code

```html
     <table class="table table-stripped table-hover">
                                        <thead>
                                            <tr>
                                                <th>Account Name</th>
                                                <th>Account Value</th>
                                                <th>Email</th>
                                                <th>Account Status</th>
                                                <th></th>
                                            </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody>
                                           {% for i in datas %}
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>{{i.engagementName}}</td>
                                                <td>{{i.engagementValue}}</td> 
                                                <td>{{i.email}}</td>
                                                <td>{{i.status}}</td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <a href="#editEmployeeModal" class="edit" data-toggle="modal" 
                                                    onclick="editengagementDetails(
                                                       name = '{{i.engagementName}}',
                                                      
                                                         
                                                        engagement_id = '{{ i.id }}',
                                                        email = '{{i.email}}',
                                                        status ='{{i.status}}'
                                                        );" ><i
                                                            class="fa fa-edit" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Edit"></i></a>
                                                    <!-- <a href="{% url 'deleteclient' i.id %}" class="delete" ><i
                                                        class="fa fa-trash" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Delete"></i></a> -->
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                    
                                            {% endfor %}
                                        </tbody>
```

Comment: You have added engagementName  in the `Meta.ordering` so the resulting queryset should be ordered in ascending order of engagement name by default. You can add status in that list as well. If you don't need to change the default ordering of results, you can call the order_by method on the queryset. e.g `qs.order_by('engagementName', 'status')`

Comment: Where should I write the command

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the order when you create the queryset by using .order_by('field_name').

You can combine your include filters in one place with Q

Eg, at the top of your views.py import Q

```
from django.db.models import Q
```

Then when you make your recordsets

```
datas_list = Engagement.objects.filter(
    Q(status="Active") | Q(status="Completed")
).order_by("engagementName", "status")
```

This will sort by Account Name and then By Status, eg first all of Susan's actives and then all her completes. You can add the same order_by to your 'if query' recordset construction.

If you have a small number of possible statuses you could avoid using Q by chaining excludes eg,

```
Engagement.objects.exclude(
    status="Incomplete"
).exclude(
    status="Inactive"
).order_by("engagementName", "status")
```

Comment: It is not working

Comment: Looks like I missed the closing quote mark in the Q(status="Completed") code.  I've updated the answer.

Comment: I have done that too

Comment: Can you tell me if it is erroring, or just not ordering correctly? What's the result and what should it be?

Comment: I need the engagementname in alphabetic order and status should display the active list first and the complete list

Comment: It is in case insesitive format